# error: no matching function for call for function pointer

Tags: c++

I created a templated BST with function to collect data:

```
typedef void (*func)(T&);

...

template<class T>
void BST<T>::inorderCollectionTraversal(func f) const
{
    inorderCollection(root,f);
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::inorderCollection(node<T> *p, func f) const
{
    if(p!=NULL){
        inorderCollection(p->leftPtr, f);
        f(p->data);
        inorderCollection(p->rightPtr, f);
    }
}
```

And then in another class, I tried to use this data structure to sort objects of another class. I am unable to extract the objects from the BST:

```
map<string, BST<Weather> > dataByMonth;

dataByMonth.find(monthCount[i]+eYear)->second.inorderCollectionTraversal(collectData); // the error points to this line

void Query::collectData(Weather& w){
    collector.push_back(w);
}
```

Everything else was tested with no issue. Only this is not working. The error message is :

```
No matching function for call to 'BST<Weather>::inorderCollectionTraversal(<unresolved overloaded function type>)

candidate: void BST<T>::inorderCollectionTraversal(BST<T>::func) const [with T

error: no matching function for call to 'BST<MetData>::inorderCollectionTraversal(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'|
include\BST.h|235|note: candidate: void BST<T>::inorderCollectionTraversal(BST<T>::func) const [with T = MetData; BST<T>::func = void (*)(MetData&)]|
include\BST.h|235|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'BST<MetData>::func {aka void (*)(MetData&)}'|
```

Can anyone advise where I went wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Looks like something is trying to call `BST::inorderCollectionTraversal()`, which was not given any arguments, and does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

`BST::func` is declared as a pointer to a standalone function, but you are trying to pass it a class method when calling `inorderCollectionTraversal(collectData)`.  If `collectData()` is not declared as `static` (which your code implies, assuming `collector` is a non-static member of `Query`), then this will not work, as `collectData()` has an implicit `this` parameter that `func` does not populate when called.

Consider changing `func` to use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead:

```
std::function<void(T&)> func;
```

And then you can use a lambda to invoke `collectData()`:

```
...->second.inorderCollectionTraversal([this](Weather &w){ collectData(w); });
```

Or even just push into `collector` directly:

```
...->second.inorderCollectionTraversal([&](Weather &w){ collector.push_back(w); });
```

Comment: Appreciate ur input. I tried it with ur suggestion but it  creates more errors pointing to the std::

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11 or later enabled? Did you add `#include <functional>` to your code?